# narrowing why server post from perl web app fails on ec2

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, perl

**Update:** I corrected the below permission issue and I can read the log files dancer generates. There was a small code bug, fixed. So now the logs display nothing, but my POST request still just fails silently! :'(

**Update 2** : I fixed it by just giving write permissions to `/srv/www/domain.com/MyApp/logs`

I have:

1. An amazon-ec2 instance with the Amazon Linux AMI.
2. It has apache2, running a perl dancer app on cgi as [described here](http://advent.perldancer.org/2010/10).

I have code doing OAuth with github API. Works perfect well on my machine but the final **POST fails on** amazon.

This may seem like a dev question, but I'm a beginner with linux sysadmin and I want clues as to how I should **narrow my problem down**.

This is my code:

```
my $browser                = LWP::UserAgent->new;
#alteast from the browser, seems like this POST never happens.
my $resp                   = $browser->post($github_post_url,
[
 client_id                  => $client_id,
 client_secret              => $client_secret, 
 code                       => $code,
 state                      => $state
]);
die "error while fetching: ", $resp->status_line
unless $resp->is_success;

my %querystr = parse_query_str($resp->decoded_content);
my $acc = $querystr{access_token};

if($acc) {
        #code to retrive access token...
    redirect $github_auth_success;
    return;
} 
    return redirect "/fail";#<<< THIS HAPPENS
```

The logs from here (tail /srv/www/domain.com/logs/error.log ) for this app say:

> log directory /srv/www/domain.com/MyApp/bin/.. isn't writable/executable and can't chmod it at /usr/local/share/perl5/Dancer/Logger.pm line 16.

But my /bin directory IS writable! And executable for everyone!

- How do I figure what is really happening here? Do I look at some other log somewhere?
- Could amazon-ec2 be blocking the outgoing post? There doesn't seem to be any outbound rule I can set in the security groups?

Comment: The message isn't about the bin directory, it's about the MyApp/ directory - see the ".." after the "bin/". Is that directory writable / executable?

Comment: @John Oh so MyApp needs to be writable? I was wondering about those dots.

Comment: According to this error message it does, yes.

Comment: For some odd reasons there was a logs folder created **under** `MyApp`, I set this writable and I got the right error! :S Still can't getting to the botom of why that post doesn't work.

Comment: Seems there was a small bug with code I wrote to detect the response code from my `LWP::UserAgent` object. Fixed it, and seems the response code is `Nothing`!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls -al /srv/www/domain.com/MyApp/`

What are the permissions set to on the `bin` directory?

Whatever user is running your perl script needs to have read/write access to that log directory.

You can `chmod` the directory (literally 'change mode') like so `chmod +600 /srv/www/domain.com/MyApp/bin`

It's better to put your log directory somewhere expected like `/var/log/MyApp` but that's beside the point. 'var' is for 'variable data', like logs. ;-)

Comment: If I do `ls -al` I get: `drwxrwxrwx 2 ec2-user ec2-user  4096 Dec 30 07:46 bin`

Comment: bah! Even after doing `chmod 777` on both bin and `MyApp` the log gives me the same thing!!!?

Comment: Hey Joseph!I updated my question